# Force Windows Update to update all components?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-update

I'm running Windows 8 and 8.1 on two computers. They have the base operating system, Office and Visual Studio installed. There are no third party apps or Windows Store apps (installed by me).

I have Windows Update set to *"Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows"*. I just finished a *Check → Update → Reboot* cycle (with a re-check) so that no updates are outstanding.

I opened Visual Studio, and lo and behold, there are outstanding updates:

[image]

I then checked the Metro screen, and there are more outstanding updates:

[image]

How do I force Windows Update to update all components, and not just some of them?

---

This situation is depressingly reminiscent of the 1990s, when update was so fractured. Its almost like a regression occurred in Windows Update.

The broken update mechanism is a disservice to product users and other internet users because we know the top two vectors for bad guys is user phishing and unpatched software. So the bad guy burrows in on me due to unpatched software, and then harasses internet users at large...

Comment: Comments for the downvote, please ... (I'm trying to understand what's not clear with what I asked, or what's wrong with the question).

Answer (score 2):

In the [Store Settings you can select that all Store Apps are updated automatically](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/automatic-app-updates-help). Set this option.

The message in Visual Studio comes from an Visual Studio extension. This is independent from Windows. In the VS2015 option you can also turn on automatic updates for Visual Studio extensions:

[image]

Comment: *"In the Store Settings..."* - I don't have access to the Store App screen. Microsoft has me locked out of my old Hotmail account. A few years ago I tried to contact Microsoft about it, but its impossible (or nearly impossible) to get support from Microsoft for free services. So I just abandoned the account. Hence the reason I want the updates to be installed through Windows Update. (Plus, that's what Windows Update is for).

Comment: *"The message in Visual Studio comes from an Visual Studio extension..."* - in this case, Microsoft installed it, so they are responsible for it. I don't buy into that crap from the free software world, where something is installed and then the folks installing it say *"hey, its not my problem"*. Hence the reason I want the updates to be installed through Windows Update. (Plus, that's what Windows Update is for).

Comment: no WindowsUpdate is for updating Windows+Office+SQL server + other dev tools, but not for updating store apps. This is done visa store.

Comment: When Microsoft made them part of the Operating System, they became a Windows System Component. They are even burned into the ROM image for the Surface tablets I use for testing. (Whether they should be part of the operating system is a different debate. I think you and I agree they should not be).

Comment: VS Addons are not part of Windows. I answered your question and now I'm out. Send feedback to MS.

Answer (score 1):

Force Update the Windows Store :

To make the Store app check for updates of installed apps via a direct command,
use the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut to open the Run dialog and type:

```
ms-windows-store:updates
```

Or run the following command :

```
explorer.exe ms-windows-store:updates
```

You may create a shortcut that contains this command and can also
pin it to the Start screen or to the Taskbar.

---

Visual Studio :

Users of Visual Studio versions prior to 2015 could possible use the extension
[Visual Studio Auto Updater](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/14973bbb-8e00-4cab-a8b4-415a38d78615) as a partial solution.
Visual Studio 2015 has better built-in mechanisms.